# What are some good alternative textbooks in international trades for undergraduates other than 'Taylor & Feenstra' and 'Krugman, Obstfeld & Melitz'?

Tags: reference-request, international-trade, international-economics, teaching, textbooks

I've been referring to the textbooks International Economics by Alan M. Taylor and Robert C. Feenstra and International Trade: Theory and Policy by Marc Melitz, Maurice Obstfeld, and Paul Krugman since I studied international trade back in my undergraduate. To me, neither textbook is clear enough to provide a good explanation of the international trade theory.

Taylor and Feenstra never gives a clear and precise description of the model assumptions and throws out some messy diagrams and 'general equations' without showing how they come. There are a lot of complementary real-life examples, but to me, they are not good enough to provide a rigours understanding of the model.

Krugman, Obstfeld and Melitz has a slightly better flow in explaining the theoretical model, provides more reference to how things are developed. But it also has the issue of making unclear assumptions.

Now I'm teaching an undergraduate-level international trade course as a newbie instructor. And I really can't find a good alternative textbook other than these two as far as I know. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!